# How to run some configuration commands to allow for a Makefile to run properly in a data processing project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, configuration

I am using a Makefile to run relatively small data science processing projects (typically involving running around 10-15 python scripts).

I want to have my project folder set up properly at the beginning of the makefile, which does certain things that will allow another user to replicate the process including:

- create a substitution drive to avoid long file paths with spaces that are out of my control
- create folders to house output data
- create and setup a new python environment

I have tried to do this in the following manner:

```
config :
    subst A: "B:\Network Drive\with-lots\Of Spaces (and other issues)"
    mkdir output-data
    conda create -n new_env 
    conda activate new_env
    pip install requirements.txt


output-data/file1.csv : script_one.py Q:/inputfile1.csv
    python $^ $@

...
```

The main issue here is that running this more than once will give an error causing make to stop, since the path substitution will have been done, the directory will have already been created, and the environment is already set up.

Is there a better approach that would allow the `config` phony target to be run only once, or at least have it run every command that it needs to run without shutting down due to an error?

Or is there a better approach for having a replicable environment set up for someone else to get it going on their own system, i.e. outside the Makefile?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a marker empty file to indicate that the configuration step has already been done:

```
.config.done:
    subst A: "B:\Network Drive\with-lots\Of Spaces (and other issues)"
    mkdir output-data
    conda create -n new_env 
    conda activate new_env
    pip install requirements.txt
    touch $@

output-data/file1.csv: .config.done script_one.py Q:/inputfile1.csv
    python $^ $@

...
```

But a better solution would be to have a way to know if each configuration step has been done or not by looking at a result file or directory. `mkdir output-data`, for instance, is easy: if `output-data` exists we know it has been done, so you could add `output-data` as an order-only prerequisite of the next step (order-only because it is a directory and you care only about its existence, not its last modification time). This way if one step fails the corresponding file or directory is not be created, the complete make run fails and after fixing what needs to be you can restart the configuration from where it stopped.

If you do not have a resulting file or directory to look at for some steps you can use the same empty file trick as above.

You could then describe your configuration with a much finer grain:

```
.PHONY: config

config: .requirements.installed

.requirements.installed: .new_env.activated
    pip install requirements.txt
    touch $@

.new_env.activated: .new_env.created
    conda activate new_env
    touch $@

.new_env.created: | output-data
    conda create -n new_env
    touch $@

output-data: .subst-A.done
    mkdir $@

.subst-A.done:
    subst A: "B:\Network Drive\with-lots\Of Spaces (and other issues)"
    touch $@

output-data/file1.csv: config script_one.py Q:/inputfile1.csv
    python $^ $@
```

By removing some dependencies you can even parallelize the configuration (if you run make with the `-j` option):

```
.PHONY: config

config: .subst-A.done .new_env.activated .requirements.installed | output-data

.requirements.installed:
    pip install requirements.txt
    touch $@

.new_env.activated: .new_env.created
    conda activate new_env
    touch $@

.new_env.created:
    conda create -n new_env
    touch $@

output-data:
    mkdir $@

.subst-A.done:
    subst A: "B:\Network Drive\with-lots\Of Spaces (and other issues)"
    touch $@

output-data/file1.csv: config script_one.py Q:/inputfile1.csv
    python $^ $@
```

Comment: This was very helpful; thank you for taking time to answer it. I had been wondering about making dummy files to signal completion of events so that's good to know it's a viable method.